# Why can't I save an emergency phone number in my addressbook?

Tags: contacts, mi-a1

I live in Thailand, and the emergency medical response number to dial here is 1669.

When I try to save this number in my address book on Android, it says "Emergency Number Cannot Be Saved".

What gives? It's probably the most important number for me to save, and I can't. Is there any way to fix this?

- My device isn't rooted.
- I'm saving to an address book that is synced via CardDAV.
- I'm running Android 8.0.0 on a Xiaomi Mi A1.

Comment: Must be carrier related, check with them. On the same device I can add any number

Comment: And probably it gets dialled automatically from power menu > emergency . Check that. If that is the case because it is programmed to dial automatically you may not be able to save it as a contact. Guess work

Comment: It could be carrier-related: It wouldn't surprise me. What is the "Power Menu"? Do you mean the lock screen?

Comment: When you press the power key you have three options, one of them is emergency (others being power off and restart). Select emergency and see which number is being dialled. In my case there is no number assigned

Comment: Pressing the "emergency" button just brings up a dialpad, I have to type a phone number manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening but can offer a workaround, if you're able to create a new contact in a web browser and have that sync to your Android phone. After sync, the number is functional on the phone.

For Google Contacts, create a new contact on https://contacts.google.com/ and it should be synced automatically.

Also tested using Fastmail (relying on a third-party app to sync CardDAV contacts).

Comment: Google contacts on the web browser works the same way. Confirmed.

Comment: Using google contacts from browser helped as well, it is a weird thing that they restrict adding most important numbers to contacts, has someone investigated why this happen?

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. But do you know *why* Google Contacts doesn't let you save an emergency number?

Comment: @Flimm Truly I don't. They must be working on the assumption that everyone knows the emergency numbers, no-matter where they live in the world. Maybe those people have never lived abroad.

Comment: My guess is that Google takes on legal liability somehow if it has emergency phone numbers in the contacts app. It doesn't want to be sued if someone tries to phone an emergency phone number and blames Google for a bug.